# Live USB: How do i save files on hard drive

Tags: live-usb, disk

So I have never used linux or ubuntu before so at the moment I am just trying it out from a USB drive. My problem is that i would like to save files on the internal hard drive of the computer but i have no idea how. Everythime i try saving something it only gives me an option to save on the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

When prompted to save something, you will usually (depending on the program) see a dialog box prompting you to click on folders to navigate to the directory in which you want to save a file. On the left hand side of this dialog box, you should see two hard disk volume logos: one for "File System" and one for your internal hard disk. From there, click on the one for your hard disk and navigate to the directory in which you want to save your files.

---

EDIT:

I now understand your question better. As you may know, the live session typically uses your RAM and then saves any changes you make to the persistence file. Even small changes can take up a lot of space. One thing you can do is [create a persistence file on your hard disk and direct the live session to use that persistence file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence). It is not clear whether you will still run out of room, or if Ubuntu will be smart and write Steam's changes to the persistent file on the hard disk.

Comment: I know where it is supposed to show up but it doesnt it only gives me one option which is the USB drive. For example when i try to install Dota 2 on steam i am not able to change to any other form of memory other than the USB

Comment: Edited to include more info.

Comment: is there any way to change where ubuntu auto saves things?

Comment: The solution I provided would be it.

Comment: would using the ubuntu cloud to save my files be another solution?

Comment: It would be very difficult and cumbersome to save entire programs to the cloud and have them run. The link in my answer provides instructions on how to save *all* of the changes you make to a file on your hard disk rather than to your USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for and run the "Disks" program from the Unity Dash.
2. You should be able to see a list of disks and partitions.
3. Find and click the disk partition you access from Windows.
4. Select the "Mount Volume" option to mount the partition.
5. Access the mounted partition from Nautilus File Manager.

Comment: I just tested this, and it worked fine.  If this doesn't work for you, please highlight what the issue you had was.

Comment: OP wants datum from the live session to be automatically saved to the hard disk.